# Runtime Error in Python code for reversing a number using a function

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting a Runtime Error saying:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'intreverse(368)'

What could be the solution for this problem?

This is my code:

```
def intreverse(n):
    rev=0
    dig=0
    while(n>=0):
        dig=n%10
        rev=rev*10+dig
        n=n//10
n=int(input("enter the number:"))
rev=intreverse(n)
print("Reverse is",rev)
```

Comment: your `intreverse` function returns nothing, so `None` is returned

Comment: What are you typing in when your program propmts `enter the number`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I am giving an integer as an input as I have to find the reverse of that integer. Ex:- 1729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to reverse an integer (ex. `intreverse(123) = 321`)

Your function have two issues,

1. No `return` value (your function always returns `None`)
2. The `while` loop enters an infinite run (`intreverse(123)` returns `321000...0` because `n=n//10` will never break the condition `n>=0` for any positive `n`)

Hence, I would fix the above two problems by re-writing your function as per the following,

```
def intreverse(n):
    rev=0
    dig=0
    while(n > 0):
        dig = n%10
        rev = rev*10 + dig
        n = n//10
    return rev

n=int(input("enter the number:"))
rev=intreverse(n)
print("Reverse is",rev)
```

> **Limitations**: Above code will fail to reverse a number with zeros in its least-significant place (as in case-2 below)
>
> 1. `intreverse(123001)` will return `100321` which is OK
> 2. `intreverse(123000)` will return `321`

If case-2 (above) is of interest to you, then I would recommend to cast the `integer` into a `string` & reverse the string as per the following code.

```
def gen_intreverse(n):
    s = str(n)
    rev = ''
    for letter in s:
        rev = letter + rev
    return rev
```

Or you can simply use the `[::-1]` modifier as per the following

```
def gen_intreverse(n):
    s = str(n)
    return s[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def gen_intreverse(n):
    return str(n)[::-1]
```

will return reversed string. `intreverse(123001)` will return `"100321"`
if you want int value. just `int()` to output value.